# Python - my While loop does not detect integer in variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

While writing an assignment for Python training, I encountered something strange.
The code:

```
number = 0
while number is not int:
    try:
        number = int(input("Give a number to start counting with: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid number!')

print("the computer starts counting at number: ", number)
```

No matter what I fill in as value for number, the while loop runs. Filling in a 0 or 6 or even a letter, the while loop runs.
If I add:

```
print(type(number))
```

to it, than it even says it is an integer. So why does the while loop not detect that?
For now the program does what I want, but I find it strange behaviour that I don't understand.

Comment: You want `not isinstance(number, int)`. Right now you're checking if `number` is the literal `int`. As in, the _class_ `int`. And it's not - it's an _instance_ of `int`, but it's not the class itself.

Answer (score 4):

to check the type of `number` you have to do `if type(number) is not int`,
but to correctly build your loop you have to do like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Give a number to start counting with: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid number!')

print("the computer starts counting at number: ", number)
```

in fact you fon't need to check `number`'s type in order to stop the loop, the `break` inside the `try: ... except:` statement will do your work